# When I try to draw the circle nothing appears on the screen

Tags: android, xml, geometry

Here is my `MainActivity` file code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my `activity_main.xml` code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

       tools:context="com.example.vinaykumar.sample.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <View android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/myfile"/>
     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my `myfile.xml` code (in which I am creating a circle)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#78d9ff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Above is the image of the file location[image]

My question is when I run my program, it doesn't show anything on the screen or not create the circle. I am new to android, so I don't know what am I doing wrong. Sorry, if it's a lot of code, but I think it'll be more clear if I show everything in my program. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is too bulky code. Are you trying to create an Circular Imageview inside which image is set to be.
There are many great library to draw Circular Imageview  by just putting some xml code without doing lots of code.

Comment: @ShivamSharma No, I'm not trying to create a circular imageview. I'm just trying to create a circle. And, yes I'm also trying to do it with just xml code and the rest of the code is already been typed for you when you create the file.

Comment: are you trying to show myFile.xml drawable over toolbar? If am I right then I've a solution for you.

Comment: @ShivamSharma I want the circle to be shown on the screen. I am new to android, so I don't know what does it mean to show on toolbar.

Comment: then first ,you must to know what is appbarlayout , toolbar, actionbar. Because your code is actually trying to draw circle shape on toolbar that is why it is overlapped by toolbar

Comment: my given code is working and it draws the circle shape on toolbar. But  more appropriate is that you  add your  view tag  into  Relativelayout and check the results.

Comment: because you don't know more about toolbar , so I help you li'l more.Check out my edited code in my answer and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistakes:**

1)The way you're doing to show drawable over toolbar is incorrect.

2)Drawable file you are designed gives you a **OVAL** shape instead of **CIRCLE** shape.

**My Solutions:**

> **Solution 1)** *Xml Code:*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >


 <!-----------------  THIS IS TOOLBAR TAG, you're using ---------------------->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar                   
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            >

        <View android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/myfile"/>

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
          android:id="@+id/fab"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
          android:layout_margin="40dp"
          app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> **Solution 2)** myfile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#78d9ff"/>

        <size
            android:width="120dp"
            android:height="120dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

<----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

> **Edited Code After conversation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <View android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/myfile"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

**myfile.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#78d9ff"/>

        <size
            android:width="120dp"
            android:height="120dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: @Hemlata it's mine pleasure. :)